# Python IDE for Debian

Tags: python, ide, django, debian

I am a Debian "stretch" (now "testing") user.

I've recently started a Python3 + Django project.

Which IDE would you advise?

I prefer software which comes with Debian, but may install something if it is really good.

Comment: What features do you need? As curently put, it's a bit vague and provokes list-type answers. Please be a bit more specific – see: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: @Izzy I need an IDE for Python Django development on my local PC. It is all I know about features I need

Answer (score 5):

**[PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm)** is available for Linux as a whole. This includes Debian. This ought to be applicable for your sort of application. You could give the community edition a try.

[image: PyCharm]
<sup>PyCharm 4.5.1 running under Ubuntu MATE (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm); click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted.  It answers the question of what will work with Debian.  It might not come with Debian, but because "really good" is a subjective thing, I think it meets the criteria

Comment: @gabe3886 Downvote was before my edit (I've added the link and the screenshot), and thus was most likely for "low quality" (references missing). By the requirements listed in the question, this now definitely is a fitting answer – though it couldn't hurt to add a few reasons on why this product is recommendable :)

Answer (score 1):

PyDev is a Python IDE for Eclipse, which may be used in Python, Jython and IronPython development.

It comes with many features such as:

- Django integration
- Code completion
- Code completion with auto import
- Syntax highlighting
- Code analysis
- Go to definition
- Refactoring
- Mark occurrences
- Debugger
- Remote debugger
- Tokens browser
- Interactive console
- Unittest integration
- Code coverage

Best of all PyDev can be installed in Debian Stretch (testing) from the default Debian repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-pydev
```

To get started with Django in PyDev, the prerequisite is that Django is installed in the Python/Jython/IronPython interpreter you want to use.